# Reactjs: How to fetch child object data in react-redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

The API gives data(JSON format) in the following fashion:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "address": {
        "street": "",
        "pin_code": 69856,
        "country": "US",
        "city": "Boston"
     }
  }
]
```

How can I fetch the fields from `address` from the above response? I'm using react-redux form.

Here is form field:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class FetchUserForm extends Component {
 render() {
   const { fields: {name, street, country}, handleSubmit } = this.props;
   return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='User Name' {...name}/>
      </div>

      <div className='form-group'>
        <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='Street' {...street}/>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='country' {...country}/>
      </div>

      <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'> Update </button>
      <button type='reset' className='btn btn-default'> Cancel </button>
    </form>
  );
 }
}

export default reduxForm ({
  form: 'FetchUserForm',
  fields: ['name', 'street', 'country']
},null, { fetchUser })(FetchUserForm);
```

As seen, I'm trying to fetch street and country from the child object of the data. Can someone pls help me get the actual data in the form. For now I'm getting `null`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to show the code/component where you are using this form. Yet, I'm guessing somewhere in your other/same component your should be calling `initialize` from `redux-form`. Since, you haven't provided much information, I'm assuming some things here, but overall this is how it should be:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { initialize } from 'redux-form';

class SomeClass extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
     const myInitialValues = {
       initialValues: {
          "name": this.props.user.name,
          "street": this.props.user.address.street, //note this
          "country": this.props.user.address.country //and this
       }
     }
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
       return(
           <FetchUserForm {...myInitialValues} onSubmit={this.someFunction.bind(this)}/>      
       );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return{
    user:state.user
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{someAction})(SomeClass);
```

Check how I've declared variable/field names in `initialValues`object. That is how it can be usually done. Hope you got an overall idea..